# CatBoost and compare_models() issue in python

Tags: python, model, compare, catboost, pycaret

Using PyCaret, when I apply a compare_models(), and that a catboost is found to be the best, I cannot print it, while I can do it for all the others. So I cannot use it to test predictions, for example.

[image: Screeshot of the issue]

I'm using PyCaret version 2.2.0 and Python version 3.8.5 64-bit. I'm on Mac (Big OS).

See What I've got with another model juste beside :

[When it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Y0e.png)

Comment: what would you expect from print? print works but only says catboostmodel. This is because print just calls the `__repr__` function of a python class and this defaults to `module.submodule.class object at <some location>`. This is what you see

Comment: If I print(best_model) for other, the screen output is ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=False, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                     criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features='auto',
                     max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                     min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                     min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                     min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1,
                     oob_score=False, random_state=26, verbose=0,
                     warm_start=False)

Comment: It means that I can use it, for example, best_model.predict(X). This is ok with any model except catboost

Comment: yes but this is just the implementation of catboost. In your screenshot the print works as intended by catboost. Print just does not print parameters

Comment: The other models come from the scikit-learn library and hence have another `__repr__` method. catboost is a module itself implemented in a completely different way

Comment: Ahhh! Okkkkay! Thanks for that. I thought it was refactored. So I just have to use it as I do outside pycaret. Thanks for the explanation.